# multcomp::cld() decreasing argument has no effect on output

Tags: r, emmeans

I´m doing some statistical tests and, as one does, wanted to look at some compact letter displays. After that, I decided that it would be nice to reverse the letter order in a way that the highest value is assinged "A". This was solved with the decreasing argument of the cld function in the past but somehow it has no effect.

Here is some example code:

```
model = lm(breaks~tension,data=warpbreaks) # a simple linear model
emg = emmeans::emmeans(model,pairwise~tension) # computing all pairwise comparisons


# computing the compact letter display with increasing order
multcomp::cld(emg[[1]],adjust="fdr",alpha=0.05,decreasing=F,Letters=LETTERS)

#Output:
# tension emmean  SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
# H         21.7 2.8 51     14.7     28.6  A    
# M         26.4 2.8 51     19.5     33.3  A    
# L         36.4 2.8 51     29.5     43.3   B   
#
#Confidence level used: 0.95 
#Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 3 estimates 
#P value adjustment: fdr method for 3 tests 
#significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
#NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping letter,
#      then we cannot show them to be different.
#      But we also did not show them to be the same.

# computing the compact letter display with decreasing order
multcomp::cld(emg[[1]],adjust="fdr",alpha=0.05,decreasing=T,Letters=LETTERS) 

#Output: 
# tension emmean  SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
# H         21.7 2.8 51     14.7     28.6  A    
# M         26.4 2.8 51     19.5     33.3  A    
# L         36.4 2.8 51     29.5     43.3   B   
#
#Confidence level used: 0.95 
#Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 3 estimates 
#P value adjustment: fdr method for 3 tests 
#significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
#NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping letter,
#      then we cannot show them to be different.
#      But we also did not show them to be the same.
```

My R Version is 4.2.0, multcomp Version is 1.4-20 and emmeans Version is 1.8.0.

I also tried mixed linear models from the lmerTest package.
I will try reinstalling the newest version of R but I observed it on my other systems with various versions of R aswell.

Sorry for bumpy english, not a native speaker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument you want is `reversed`, not `decreasing`:

```
> multcomp::cld(emg[[1]],adjust="fdr",alpha=0.05,reversed=FALSE,Letters=LETTERS)
 tension emmean  SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 H         21.7 2.8 51     14.7     28.6  A    
 M         26.4 2.8 51     19.5     33.3  A    
 L         36.4 2.8 51     29.5     43.3   B   

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 3 estimates 
P value adjustment: fdr method for 3 tests 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
      then we cannot show them to be different.
      But we also did not show them to be the same. 
> 
> multcomp::cld(emg[[1]],adjust="fdr",alpha=0.05,reversed=TRUE,Letters=LETTERS)
 tension emmean  SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 L         36.4 2.8 51     29.5     43.3  A    
 M         26.4 2.8 51     19.5     33.3   B   
 H         21.7 2.8 51     14.7     28.6   B   

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 3 estimates 
P value adjustment: fdr method for 3 tests 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
      then we cannot show them to be different.
      But we also did not show them to be the same.
```

#### Addendum

I added a `decreasing` argument to `cld.emmGrid()` that may be used interchangeably with `reversed`. This provides compatibility with `multcomp::cld.glht()` documentation.

```
> multcomp::cld(emg[[1]],adjust="fdr",alpha=0.05,decreasing=TRUE,Letters=LETTERS)
 tension emmean  SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 L         36.4 2.8 51     29.5     43.3  A    
 M         26.4 2.8 51     19.5     33.3   B   
 H         21.7 2.8 51     14.7     28.6   B   
    . . .
```

The confusion occurs because **emmeans** relies on `multcompView::multcompLetters()` which uses `reversed`, while **multcomp** provides its own `cld` code that uses `decreasing` instead. The update can be installed from GitHub, or eventually be included in the CRAN version.

Comment: BTW, this is a *numerical* example -- definitely not a good *practice* example, as `wool` and `tension` interact quite strongly, and marginal means are highly misleading.

Comment: Thank you, the R documentation for the cld function stated the `decreasing` argument I will report this error to the maintainer. Would a model regarding both factors and thier interaction be a better example? e.g.: `model = lm(breaks~wool*tension,data=warpbreaks)
emg = emmeans::emmeans(model,pairwise~tension*wool,alpha=0.05,adjust="fdr")
multcomp::cld(emg[[1]],alpha=0.05,adjust="fdr",Letters=LETTERS,reversed=T)`. I could update the thread to increas quality.

Comment: OK, I see that now in the documentation for `multcomp::cld()`. Their version came *before* my method in **emmeans**, so it probably would not be an issue for them. I will see if I can somehow incorporate a `decreasing` argument in `cld.emmGrid()`.

Comment: Hmmm, I now see that I am using the `reversed` argument as provided by the **multcompView** package in `multcompLetters()`. So I didn't just make that up. Nonetheless, I think I'll go ahead and try to bridge the ambiguity.